# Get column name from SUM function in JS

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a SQL query that gets a few columns, and one of them is a SUM() function, so the column name is not "normal".

The query

```
SELECT c.name,c.value,SUM(a.amount)
FROM CurrencyEntry a, Currencies c
WHERE a.currency_id=c.id
Group BY a.currency_id
ORDER BY c.value DESC
```

My output appears like this

[image]

using JS, I can get the column names and data of `name` and `value`, and this works fine:

```
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row.name + "-" + row.value)
        });
    });
```

But I don't know how to get the data out of `SUM(a.amount)` column.

Is there a way to change the name of the column in the query so I can reference it like the other columns, or a way to get the data out of this column using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct your query statement like this

```
SELECT c.name,c.value,SUM(a.amount) as amount // here is change
FROM CurrencyEntry a, Currencies c
WHERE a.currency_id=c.id
Group BY a.currency_id
ORDER BY c.value DESC
```

then your script should be

```
db.all(sql, [], (err, rows) => {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            console.log(row.name + "-" + row.value + "-" + row.amount)
        });
    });
```